# iPhone displaying Empty Smart App Banner for an app?

Tags: ios, iphone, smartbanner

As per the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH6-SW6), I put:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=MY_APP_ID">
```

in the HTML's head but the banner is not coming up in India where the app is available.

iPhone displays an empty, grey banner with a close button and nothing else. I'd expected it to show corresponding app banner.

I am unable to figure out what's issue. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you connected with a “real” Apple ID associated with a country where the app is available? Sandbox ids or ids associated to other countries may prevent the banner from appearing.

Comment: @jcaron, Thank you so much. I was logged in using another country app id. It's working now.